# How to create anchor links in Drupal in the main menu as a single-page site?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

when i want to create single-page website so i need to create menu with "href" like "#id"'s.
and in Drupal after create menu from **Structure -> Menus** i need add real url in database;
how can i assign id`s front page in Structure -> Menus ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this path  <"front">#id like  <"front">#contact  in path menu . and front don't need "" .